# Firefox 4 Downgrades to Firefox 3.6 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox, firefox-3.6

On my Windows 7 x64 computer, Firefox 4 has seamlessly downgraded itself to Firefox 3.6 twice.  I haven't determined exactly when this is occurring, but the second time was when restarting after adding GreaseMonkey.  It is possible the first time was also after adding an add-on.

Re-upgrading to 4.0 seems to work perfectly.

How can I stop this from happening again?

Answer (score 5):

It may be a problem within your profile.

Personally I would backup the contents of `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox` (Just Rename the directory)

Then uninstall Firefox completely, go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla\` (Mozilla Firefox, whatever it is) and make sure that directory doesn't exist or if it does, check the contents, backup if necessary and remove.

Re-install Firefox, it should be a fresh installation now, give the update a try and see what happens after.

Answer (score 0):

When I went to look at uninstalling I noticed that I had Firefox 3 Beta 5 still installed.  I have uninstalled it, and expect it will solve my problems.